# Different shards in a SolrCloud set up with different solrconfig's?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'd like to set up SolrCloud with one collection consisting of three different shards.

I understand that since a collection represents **a single logical index**, it must have **a single schema**.  I'm wondering, however, if each shard can have a **different solrconfig**?

Despite a fair amount of searching, I haven't seen any examples where a collection consists of a single schema but multiple solrconfig's. The SolrCloud tutorials I've worked through all init the collection with one bootstrapping config:

```
java -Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/collection1/conf -Dcollection.configName=myconf -DzkRun -DnumShards=2 -jar start.jar
```

However, there are some elements in SolrCloud documentation that leads me to believe a SolrCloud set up with a single schema yet different solrconfig files for each shard might be possible. From "Solr Glossary":

> "***Collection**: In Solr, one or more documents grouped together in a single logical index. A collection must have a single schema, but can be spread across multiple cores.*"

If a collection must have a single schema, but can consist of multiple cores, is that an indication that these different cores can have different solrconfig's?  If so, how can this be set up?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Collection is a logical container for the same configuration. You cannot have cores with different configuration in single collection.
In general, you may query several collections (see SolrCloud wiki for that), if those collections have same schema. This will work only if both collections reside on the same zookeeper cluster. Give it a try.